# Attempted to call function "iconv_strlen"

Tags: php, symfony

Passei a usar o Manjaro e de repente este erro sem nenhuma outra informação está aparecendo. Antes no Debian estava tudo funcional. Faz alguns dias que não modifico nada. O erro é

> Attempted to call function "iconv_strlen" from namespace "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger".

E também tem este:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "iconv_strlen" from namespace "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger"." at /home/gabriel/NetBeansProjects/CasaDoGesso/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Logger/DbalLogger.php line 102

Alguma sugestão do que deve ser feito?

Answer (score 2):

O `iconv` é instalado por padrão (compilado) nas versões atuais, mas pode ser que eventualmente o *PHP* tenha sido compilado usando a *flag* `--without-iconv`, se este for o caso e você não tiver acesso ao servidor para reinstalar o PHP, você pode instalar o "polyfill" para [Symfony](https://symfony.com) usando [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md):

1. Navegue até a pasta do projeto:

   ```
   cd /home/gabriel/NetBeansProjects/CasaDoGesso
   ```
2. Digite isto (tem que ter o `composer` instalado):

   ```
   composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv
   ```

Repositório: [symfony/polyfill](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill)

### Outros polyfills para Symfony

Instale conforme necessário usando `composer require`

- `symfony/polyfill-apcu` para usar as funções `apcu_`
- `symfony/polyfill-php54` para usar as funções do PHP 5.4 em versões anteriores
- `symfony/polyfill-php55` para usar as funções do PHP 5.5 *
- `symfony/polyfill-php56` para usar as funções do PHP 5.6 *
- `symfony/polyfill-php70` para usar as funções do PHP 7.0 *
- `symfony/polyfill-php71` para usar as funções do PHP 7.1 *
- `symfony/polyfill-iconv` para usar as funções do `iconv`
- `symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme` para usar as funções `grapheme_*`
- `symfony/polyfill-intl-icu` para usar as funções funções e classes `intl`
- `symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer` para usar as funções `intl normalizer`
- `symfony/polyfill-mbstring` para usar as funções `mbstring`
- `symfony/polyfill-xml` para usar as funções `utf8_encode` e `utf8_decode`
- `symfony/polyfill-util` utilitários para o "polyfill"

Se necessitar (creio que bem improvável) pode instalar todos de uma vez:

```
composer require symfony/polyfill
```

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca `php-iconv` não está instalada no sistema em que você está rodando o sistema. Quando você chama o método `iconv_strlen` de um determinado namespace e esse método não existe, o PHP acha que você está tentando chamar um método no namespace atual, que também não existe.

Para resolver, basta instalar a biblioteca `php-iconv`.

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php

Comment: Correção: Função e não método...